# rerender attribute refreshing all columns in pageblocktable

Tags: rerender, pageblocktable

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!TasklstI}" var="tsk" id="table">
<apex:column rendered="{!if(ownerhide=false,true,false)}" headerValue="Assigned To"> <apex:commandLink value="{!tsk.owner.name}" action="{!editOwner}"  reRender="table"/></apex:column>
<apex:column rendered="{!if(ownerhide=true,true,false)}" headerValue="Assigned To"   > <apex:inputfield value="{!tsk.ownerId}"  /></apex:column>
</apex:pageblocktable>

public void editOwner(){
ownerhide = true;
}
```

But my requirement is when I click on hyperlink I need to get only 1 field to be editable. But here the entire column is in editable position. Am i missing anything.

I tried rerendering like this also But this is also not working

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!TasklstI}" var="tsk" >
    <apex:column rendered="{!if(ownerhide=false,true,false)}" headerValue="Assigned To"> <apex:commandLink value="{!tsk.owner.name}" action="{!editOwner}"  reRender="table"/></apex:column>
    <apex:column rendered="{!if(ownerhide=true,true,false)}" headerValue="Assigned To"  id="table" > <apex:inputfield value="{!tsk.ownerId}"  /></apex:column>
    </apex:pageblocktable>
```

Comment: It's likely to refresh your table since you're rendering whole pageblocktable. If your goal is to edit single row then better to use `inlineEdit`.

Comment: Anywayz i'm having inline edit for this pageblocktable.since its a hyperlink inlineedit  isn't working in this case

Comment: It's better to use standard inline editing provided of VF page or built a cusom one using datatable.. Have a look at this [standard inline edit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inlineEditSupport.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original problem is that the operations you've designed work on the entire column, not just a single cell. For example, the Boolean value ownerEdit is just a single value for all rows; there's no way for the code to know which row you meant. From your current design, I'd say the least amount of work would be to use a temporary record instead.

## Controller Changes

Instead of having a Boolean value, we'll identify which row we're currently editing with a temporary task.

```
public Task ownerTask { get; set; }
```

In your constructor, remember to initialize the variable:

```
ownerTask = new Task();
```

We also need a way to edit the record, so we'll add an action method:

```
// The apex:commandLink populates this value to tell us which task to edit
public transient Id ownerEditId { get; set; }

public void ownerEdit() {
  ownerTask.Id = ownerEditId;
  // One-liner "find task by Id in a List" trick
  ownerTask.OwnerId = new Map<Id, Task>(TasklstI).get(ownerEditId).OwnerId;
}
```

We also need a way to update the task when we save:

```
public void saveEdit() {
  if(ownerTask.Id != null && ownerTask.OwnerId != null) {
    // This code assumes we'll save okay. Consider error handling here.
    update ownerTask;

    // Refresh ownership display value
    Task tempTask = [SELECT Owner.Name FROM Task WHERE Id = :ownerTask.Id];
    new Map<Id, Task>(TaskLstI).get(ownerTask.Id).Owner = tempTask.Owner;

    // end edit mode
    ownerTask.Id = null;
  }
}
```

And finally a cancel option:

```
public void cancelEdit() {
  ownerTask.Id = null;
}
```

## Page Changes

Setting a rendered attribute at the apex:column level will affect all rows simultaneously. We only want to affect one row at a time, so we need to set the rendered attribute at the apex:commandLink/apex:inputField level.

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!TasklstI}" var="tsk" id="table">
  <apex:column headerValue="Assigned To">
    <apex:commandLink rendered="{!tsk.Id<>tempTask.Id}" value="{!tsk.owner.name}" action="{!ownerEdit}"  reRender="table">
      <apex:param assignTo="{!ownerEditId}" name="" value="{!tsk.Id}" />
    </apex:commandLink>
    <apex:inputfield value="{!ownerTask.ownerId}" rendered="{!tsk.Id=tempTask.Id}" />
  </apex:column>
</apex:pageblocktable>
```

---

N.B. I didn't actually model this in my developer org, so there may be a few minor issues, but this should be very close to correct.